# pandas/numpy - time based averages

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have some data that is basically a datetime stamp and a value, eg:

```
01-01-2021 11:40:01,   1.0532
01-01-2021 11:40:02,   1.0531
...
01-01-2021 11:41:01,   1.0541
01-01-2021 11:41:01,   1.0542
```

There is a lot of data.   I was wondering if there was a way to get pandas or numpy to calculate the average quickly over a timedelta such as 1 second, 5 seconds, 1 minute, 5 minutes etc.

I know that there are functions for calculating the average over a number of points, but its over a timedelta that I need, ie 1 second average, 5 second average, 1 minute average etc.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Let’s first get some random data that looks like what you describe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'datetime': pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp.today(), periods=2048, freq='300ms'),
...     'value': np.random.randint(0, 100, 2048) / 200 + 1
... })
```

If your `datetime` are strings and not actual datetimes, you should convert them first:

```
>>> df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

You can then use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to achieve what you want. For example every second:

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='1s'))['value'].mean()
datetime
2021-09-27 11:07:15    1.190000
2021-09-27 11:07:16    1.180000
2021-09-27 11:07:17    1.141250
2021-09-27 11:07:18    1.285000
2021-09-27 11:07:19    1.190000
                         ...   
2021-09-27 11:17:25    1.255000
2021-09-27 11:17:26    1.305000
2021-09-27 11:17:27    1.150000
2021-09-27 11:17:28    1.258333
2021-09-27 11:17:29    1.312500
Freq: S, Name: value, Length: 615, dtype: float64
```

Every 5 seconds:

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='5s'))['value'].mean()
datetime
2021-09-27 11:07:15    1.194286
2021-09-27 11:07:20    1.267647
2021-09-27 11:07:25    1.305000
2021-09-27 11:07:30    1.223125
2021-09-27 11:07:35    1.255294
                         ...   
2021-09-27 11:17:05    1.280882
2021-09-27 11:17:10    1.225294
2021-09-27 11:17:15    1.329687
2021-09-27 11:17:20    1.278235
2021-09-27 11:17:25    1.262353
Freq: 5S, Name: value, Length: 123, dtype: float64
```

Etc., see the [reference of frequency expressions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

Also be aware that your average might not always have the same number of values for every unit of time:

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='1s'))['value'].count()
datetime
2021-09-27 11:07:15    1
2021-09-27 11:07:16    3
2021-09-27 11:07:17    4
2021-09-27 11:07:18    3
2021-09-27 11:07:19    3
                      ..
2021-09-27 11:17:25    3
2021-09-27 11:17:26    4
2021-09-27 11:17:27    3
2021-09-27 11:17:28    3
2021-09-27 11:17:29    4
Freq: S, Name: value, Length: 615, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it isn't quite what I was after.   I presume Grouper, group's the date times into their nearest second or minute.   Ideally I would like something like the last 5 minutes, so 17:06:14, would include records back to 17:01:14.   Am I wrong about this ?   Thanks

Comment: @MarkyMark1000 It doesn’t round afaik, it bins. Do you want a rolling average, i.e. the same number of outputs as inputs? Or do you just want to shift the origin of the bins so that the last one first the current time?

Comment: thanks for the response.   I wanted the average to be over the last 5 minutes of data.   Don't worry if it isn't available, I just wondered if there was a system for calculating this.   I tried it in python directly and it was very very slow.   Looks like I will have to either bucket the data or use a rolling average on a set number of steps.   Thanks

Comment: I mean if you just want the last 5 minutes, you can use `df.loc[pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta(minutes=5):].mean()`